# document.CreateElement(div) not working...

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to create a div element on the runtime and placing a chart element inside it, which doesn't seem to work.

```
function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':400};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        //context.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
        div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.position = "absolute";
        div.style.top = "0";
        div.style.left = "0";
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

It works when i declare the div in the  of html. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `document.getElementById('div')`, but the id of the `div` you created has not been set to `div`. Why don't you just do this:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(div);
```

Another option is to actually set the id:

```
div.id = "div";
...
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('div'));
```

Comment: You beat me to it - I noticed the missing ID also. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the `id` of the div to `div`.  It seems like you should be using:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(div);
```